# Android why I can't get widget's custom attribute value outside with constructor

Tags: android

I write a custom widget and define some custom attributes belong to it.In java code,I need get those attribute values from xml,so I use the android supplied api as follow:

```
 TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.AutoSizeLayout);
 String autoSizeWidgetId = a
            .getString(R.styleable.AutoSizeLayout_whichChildAutoSize);
```

Note:attrs is AttributeSet object

But,I write these codes in View's onLayout method,I find it always returns null,when I move codes to View's constructor,it will return the value I expect.So why I can't get attribute from other methods,only constructor?

Comment: But you can parse them in the constructor and store them in membervariables to use later

Comment: As Martin has said, please refer to [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr)